# Problem wired connection ubuntu LTS 14.04

Tags: 14.04, network-manager, ethernet, wired

I have a problem with my network wired connection, my general problem is when I plug the ethernet cable it doesn't work.

But the problem is the following, if my computer is on and later I plug in the cable it doesn't work, but if my computer is off and I plug in the cable and then turn it on, the wired connection works , it's weird, but I need sometimes when my computer is on, plug in the cable and that it work.

Can you please help me to solve my problem ?.

thank you so much.

Comment: Try `sudo dhclient -v eth0`

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time on LTS 14.04 and often had similar issues with both wireless and wired.  The following always worked for me, where I was using Network Manager at the time...

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

If you're not using Network Manager, then simply try

```
sudo service networking restart
```